# Почему в jQuery при добавлении в массив выходит ошибка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь реализовать REST приложение, получаю json пакет и вывожу его в таблицу, но если при этом добавлять данные в массив выходит куча ошибок, просьба сказать что я делаю не так?

Код:

```
var lebelCh = new Array();
var dataCh = new Array();

function showAllElem(arrElem){
$('table').remove();
$('#getChart').remove();
var tbl = "<table id='reportTable'>";
tbl += "<tr><th>№ п/п</th><th>Имя</th><th>Атрибут</th></tr>
    $.each(arrElem, function(i, el) {
        tbl += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + el.name + '</td><td>' + el.index + '</td></tr>';
          lebelCh.push(el.name);//тут выходит ошибка
          dataCh.push(el.index);//тут выходит ошибка
    });

tbl += "</table>";
$(tbl).addClass('mytable').appendTo('#reportBlock');
$('#getBtn').after('<button id="getChart">Показать график</button>');
}
```

Ошибка

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: lebelCh is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:88)
at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at showAllElem (main.js:86)
at Object.success (main.js:33)
at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: "//тут выходит ошибка" - НИКОГДА!!! не говорите какая.

Comment: Извиняюсь, исправил.

Comment: переменные массивов объявлены в месте, которое не видно из кода, где Вы их используете

Comment: Спасибо, действительно не досмотрел, сделал переменные глобальными и все получилось!